# How to change the author name for a drupal account/website

Tags: drupal, web, blogs

I am currently starting a blog on drupal and on every page they have `authorName's blog`. I don't want it to display my name I want it to display my websites name as I won't have anyone else logging in.

Is there a simple way to either change my username or to change the name that the website displays?

If it helps the blog is [here](http://www.simplykyra.com/), but be warned it is extremely rudimentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ways to change the display of your username on a node:

- Change your username (Administer - Users - Edit)
- Modify your theme to remove/replace the username on the page
- Use [RealName](http://drupal.org/project/realname) to display a name that is different from your username

**Edit**
I think I misunderstood initially... you don't want `kyrajleimert's blog` at the bottom of your blog posts? Simple: **[don't use the Blog module.](http://www.onyxbits.de/content/blog/patrick/dont-use-drupals-blog-module-unless-you-intent-build-blog-hosting-site)** It's only useful if you will have multiple people posting to your site. Use the **Story** content type instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there are two solutions :

- rename your account with your site's name
- create a new account with your site's name

Answer (score 0):

You can change your username in account settings: `user/[user id]/edit`. In order to be able to do this you will need a permission.

An alternative solution would be to change the urls with path - a Drupal core module and [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto). With pathauto you can setup a rule so all blogposts will have the url: blog/[title] or blog/[company name]/[title] or whatever you like.